# how to conncect to a capnel db with a local laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

i want to connect with remote db hosted on cpanel
to do some opreations like

```
 $remoteMaxTimestamp = DB::connection('remote')->table($table)->max('updated_at');
```

but when i try to test it with postman ,it takes lots of time " Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded" i dont' know why,i have found Remote MySQL section on cpanel but i don't know is it related or not.

here is my db configrations

in .env file

```
DB_HOST_remote=0.162.205.99.host.secureserver.net:2083
DB_DATABASE_remote=name
DB_USERNAME_remote=usr
DB_PASSWORD_remote=****
```

in config/database.php file

```
'remote' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => $config['DB_HOST_remote'] ?? env('DB_HOST_remote', '0.162.205.99.host.secureserver.net:2083'),
            'port' => $config['DB_PORT'] ?? env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => $config['DB_DATABASE_remote'] ?? env('DB_DATABASE_remote', 'forge'),
            'username' => $config['DB_USERNAME_remote'] ?? env('DB_USERNAME_remote', 'forge'),
            'password' => $config['DB_PASSWORD_remote'] ?? env('DB_PASSWORD_remote', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'dump' => [
                'dump_binary_path' => 'C:/xampp/mysql/bin/', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
                'use_single_transaction',
                'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
            ],
            //'dump_command_path' => 'C:/xampp/mysql/bin/',
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ]
```

Comment: What port is your MySQL server listening on?  It's usually 3306, but your config also appears to have 2083

Comment: it's on a shred server so here is the base url where i access my cpanel and phpmyadmin dbs 
0.162.205.99.host.secureserver.net:2083

Comment: The config you need for PHP to connect to a MySQL database is for the MySQL server, not the cpanel URL.  If cpanel and MySQL are running on the same machine, then you can probably just use the same host name (just drop the ':2083' part).

Comment: Did you check whether connecting to that database is possible after all? Usually, the remote access is not enabled. Also, how is this problem related to phpMyAdmin?

Comment: i have tried to remove the  ':2083' part but gives me connection failed or time out , @RobEyre

Comment: i have mention above about idont know if it related to "Remote MySQL section on cpanel" so plz , if you know somthing about it tell me .

Answer (score 1):

you must send support ticket for your host provider to open the SQL port for remote connection and the SQL port usually is 3306